# Replace missing values with zero -2 levels different columns r

Tags: r, missing-data

I have a data set with several columns. I would like to replace missing values with when JOB = Student and HOME_VAL = 0

LOGIC if JOB == Student and HOME_VAL == ' '
  then HOME_VAL==0

```
if(DT$JOB == 'Student' & DT$HOME_VAL=='') {
    DT$HOME_VAL<-0
}
```

Data

```
HOME_VAL  JOB
$9999     Student
 $100     Home Maker
          Student
 $2000    Home Maker
          Student
 $60000   Student
 $40000   Professor
```

Looking for

```
HOME_VAL  JOB
$9999     Student
 $100     Home Maker
 0        Student
 $2000    Home Maker
 0        Student
 $60000   Student
 $40000   Professor
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `dplyr::mutate`:

```
 library(dplyr);
 library(magrittr);
 df %>%
    mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
    mutate(HOME_VAL = ifelse(HOME_VAL == "" & JOB == "Student", 0, HOME_VAL))
#  HOME_VAL        JOB
#1    $9999    Student
#2     $100 Home Maker
#3        0    Student
#4    $2000 Home Maker
#5        0    Student
#6   $60000    Student
#7   $40000  Professor
```

Explanation: `mutate_if` converts `factor` columns to `character` columns, `mutate` + `ifelse` does the replacement according to your logic.

---

Or in base R:

```
df$HOME_VAL = as.character(df$HOME_VAL);
df$HOME_VAL = ifelse(df$HOME_VAL == "" & df$JOB == "Student", 0, df$HOME_VAL);
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
   "HOME_VAL  JOB
$9999     Student
$100     'Home Maker'
''          Student
$2000    'Home Maker'
''          Student
$60000   Student
$40000   Professor", header = T)
```